# Question listed as duplicate of wrong other question

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[Can Eldritch Blast be Twinned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62566/can-eldritch-blast-be-twinned?rq=1) is currently listed as a duplicate of [Does a sorcerer's metamagic work for non-sorcerer spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53714/does-a-sorcerers-metamagic-work-for-non-sorcerer-spells), but the answer to that question is not correct for this one.  It seems to me like it should be either reopened and answered as-is or listed as a duplicate to [Does twinned spell work with magic missile?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53600/does-twinned-spell-work-with-magic-missile) - which is asking about a different spell but does have the correct answer for the correct reason.  I've voted to reopen in an attempt to get the process of a fix started, but it'll take more than just me, and it's an old enough question that I suspect it won't get where it's going without at least a bit of a push.

Just for clarity, what *is* the correct response to this sort of situation?  I feel rather strongly that "left as-is" is the wrong answer due to... well, providing the wrong answer, but what should be done with it?  Is "question about a different spell with the right answer for the right reason" enough to deserve a duplicate close, should it be answered independently, or is it that I'm just wrong and it should be left as-is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have reopened that question because it is not a duplicate of either question.

The source of OP's confusion was with the "targets only one creature and doesn't have a range of self" part of the Twinned Spell description which indicates that the confusion was not based on the spell being from a different class' spell list. So not a duplicate of the non-sorcerer question.

Aditionally, I don't think it is a direct duplicate of the magic missile question either because magic missile can target more than one creature by default while eldritch blast can only target more than one at certain levels. It is a subtle but important distinction.